# How do i get only content of replied mail by avoiding the original message in IMAP using PHP

Tags: php

I have an issue while retrieving the replied email content using IMAP: I'am getting original body including the reply content. But how do I ignore the original body except reply content?

I knew there is no predefined function to avoid original mail body.. but I still need this replied content for applicable to all replied mails.

Comment: what did you try so far?

Comment: preg_match to check  string have the lines starting the with special character > but getting empty result